# Selenium UrlContains in C#

Tags: c#, selenium

I'm trying to wait for a specific URL to load. However I don´t know the full URL, a dynamic value will be added at the end. Lets say the URL is `www.test.com/accepted/?12345`, but I only know `www.test.com/accepted/`

I´m trying to do something like this:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Generic.driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.UrlContains("www.test.com/accepted/"));
```

Is there a way to just check for the part that I know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.UrlContains("accepted"));
```

Is exactly what you need. If it doesn't work, debug the code and check the actual url and the expected url. If you get an error, please share it with us so we can help you further.

**Update 2018-04-11**

`ExpectedConditions` is now marked obsolete, the Selenium changelog now states that you should use the lambda functions directly

Example for UrlContains:

```
public static Func<IWebDriver, bool> UrlContains(string fraction)
{
    return (driver) => { return driver.Url.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(fraction.ToLowerInvariant()); };
}
```

They also created a new repository on github which might help:
https://github.com/DotNetSeleniumTools/DotNetSeleniumExtras

Comment: Actually I got `ExpectedConditions is deprecated ... ' any tips?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code for `ExpectedConditions.UrlContains(string)` as taken from the [Selenium source code](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/dotnet/src/support/UI/ExpectedConditions.cs)

```
public static Func<IWebDriver, bool> UrlContains(string fraction)
{
    return (driver) => { 
        return driver.Url.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(fraction.ToLowerInvariant()); 
    };
}
```

As you can see it implements a case insensitive partial match.

This means that if the code shown in your question isn't working it's because the URL absolutely does not contain the provided fraction, or the problem lies elsewhere that we can't see.